# How to run sublime text in Musl LibC (Void Linux)

Tags: linux, glibc, void-linux, sublime-text

How i can run sublime text in Void Linux with musl LibC (not glibc) without using chroot or flatpak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since sublime text is shareware, you're probably not in the position to re-link it to your own libc.

So, no. It needs to use a libc that is ABI-compatible with what was there at build-time. And your Musl will not be that.

Also, what do you care about a slimmer libc if you install a humongous software like sublime – the amount of relevant code in the libc is really benign compared to the millions and millions of lines of code in sublime text, and the probably multiple versions of various libc statically linked into these.

Comment: Many advocates of musl use it for security benefits; it isn't always about lower LOC counts, or smaller binaries.

Answer (score 0):

My solution has been to run it in Debian container (docker, podman, crun, etc) which uses glibc.  It's not a perfect solution, but it does offer a workable solution without including glibc on the host system.

A statically linked distribution of Sublime Text would be nice, but as mentioned by others, would require the support of the backing developers.